# Gigya SDK v4 Facebook login issue

Tags: java, android, authentication, facebook-login, gigya

I want to login via Facebook through Gigya SDK v4 . I have add the dependency

```
gigya-android-sdk-4.0.3
```

And use the below method for login

```
 HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();

 Gigya.getInstance().login(GigyaDefinitions.Providers.FACEBOOK, hashMap, new LoginCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(GigyaError gigyaError)
                {

                }
            });
```

Getting the following exception

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "socialize.null": No address associated with hostname
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "socialize.null": No address associated with hostname
2019-09-03 14:32:34.528   W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:157)
2019-09-03 14:32:34.529   W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
2019-09-03 14:32:34.529   W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
2019-09-03 14:32:34.529   W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
2019-09-03 14:32:34.530   W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
2019-09-03 14:32:34.530   W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
2019-09-03 14:32:34.530   W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
2019-09-03 14:32:34.531   W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
```

Manifest permission added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Please help to solve the error

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your implementation code cause there's no "LoginCallback" class in the SDK. I assume that you have added the Facebook SDK as instructed & added all the necessary AndroidManifest.xml entries? Also make sure you initialized the SDK correctly cause it seems you haven't specified a default domain.

Comment: Thanks @TalMihr I have forget to add domain field in gigyaSdkConfiguration.json .Now I am not getting above exception.Can you help me fetch the details after login from default Account class.

Comment: Sure. What data do you want to fetch? The default GigyaLoginCallback gives u a clear representation of the GigyaAccount object. If you want to create a custom one look at https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android+SDK+v4#AndroidSDKv4-ProvidingACustomAccountSchema